# JQuery Frame UI Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, frame

Is there a jquery plugin or UI element which emulates the HTML frame tag? I'm looking for something with a more modern jquery look, but with the same functionality as an html frame tag.

Edit: By frame functionality, I mean having the ability to display two or three html pages in one screen with a resizable bar letting the user dynamically adjust the size of each individual page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXT is way overkill, and jumping between can be seriously confusing to those of us who mostly work in jQuery.  It's definitely not a good idea to load both as you throw one into compatibility mode.  So, a Jquery option is going to likely be the best solution here.

Jquery UI is coming out with a "layout manager" that will be ideal, but it's still in development.  So, right now third party apps are your best bet.

By far, the best solution I've seen so far is [JqueryUi Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)  It gives you all that frames type layout that you will ever need and is really well written.  The one thing that I haven't ever tried on it is using separate .html files to populate areas, though I suspect if it wasn't supported you could do it via includes or AJAX.  I would argue that since this is all "front-end" type work that you could safely combine your content from separate htmls to cut down on overhead, maintenance, and confusion.

And for the record, HTML Frames are HORRIBLE.....I survived that fad (and animated gifs everywhere GAH!) and never, ever want to go back!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree that HTML frames are non-optimal, but I am trying to build a dashboard like interface where the user picks several views (different pages) and wants to see them on the same screen. I'll look into JqueryUi Layout and hopefully it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[Ext JS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html) is pretty heavyweight, but it does provide what you're looking for. Unfortunately it's not free for non-open source. An alternative would be [Wijmo's splitter](http://wijmo.com/demos/explore/#splitter%7Coverview), which has the advantage of being more lightweight, based on jQuery, and free. Unfortunately, it's not nearly as powerful as Ext. For instance, it can only collapse in one direction. Fortunately, it doesn't appear that you require that functionality.

The only other thing I can think of off the top of my head would be to hack something together with a combination of Wijmo's Superpanel and jQuery UI's resizable module. You'd have a great deal of control over the look and feel, but you'd have to take care of the resizing logic yourself. It wouldn't be very difficult or time consuming, but it doesn't really meet your request for an off the shelf component, either.